# PyParsing: parse if not a keyword

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to parse a file as follows:

`testp.txt`

```
title                               = Test Suite A;
timeout                             = 10000
exp_delay                           = 500;
log                                 = TRUE;

sect
{
    type                            = typeA;
    name                            = "HelloWorld";
    output_log                      = "c:\test\out.log";
};

sect
{
    name = "GoodbyeAll";
    type = typeB;
    comm1_req = 0xDEADBEEF;
    comm1_resp = (int, 1234366);
};
```

The file first contains a section with parameters and then some `sect`s. I can parse a file containing *just* parameters and I can parse a file *just* containing `sect`s but I can't parse both.

```py
from pyparsing import *
from pathlib import Path

command_req         = Word(alphanums)
command_resp        = "(" + delimitedList(Word(alphanums)) + ")"
kW                  = Word(alphas+'_', alphanums+'_') | command_req | command_resp
keyName             = ~Literal("sect") + Word(alphas+'_', alphanums+'_') + FollowedBy("=")
keyValue            = dblQuotedString.setParseAction( removeQuotes ) | OneOrMore(kW,stopOn=LineEnd())
param               = dictOf(keyName, Suppress("=")+keyValue+Optional(Suppress(";")))
node                = Group(Literal("sect") + Literal("{") + OneOrMore(param) + Literal("};"))
final               = OneOrMore(node) | OneOrMore(param)

param.setDebug()

p = Path(__file__).with_name("testp.txt")
with open(p) as f:
    try:
        x = final.parseFile(f, parseAll=True)
        print(x)
        print("...")
        dx = x.asDict()
        print(dx)
    except ParseException as pe:
        print(pe)
```

The issue I have is that `param` matches against `sect` so it expects a `=`. So I tried putting in `~Literal("sect")` in `keyName` but that just leads to another error:

```
Exception raised:Found unwanted token, "sect", found '\n'  (at char 188), (line:4, col:56)
Expected end of text, found 's'  (at char 190), (line:6, col:1)
```

How do I get it use one parse method for `sect` and another (`param`) if not `sect`?

My final goal would be to have the whole lot in a `Dict` with the global `params` and `sects` included.

**EDIT**
Think I've figured it out:

This line...

```py
final               = OneOrMore(node) | OneOrMore(param)
```

...should be:

```py
final               = ZeroOrMore(param) + ZeroOrMore(node)
```

But I wonder if there is a more structured way (as I'd ultimately like a dict)?